# Simple rebase - but I can't figure it out

Tags: git, github, git-rebase

My brain apparently can't handle Git. I'm trying. I'm failing.

All I want to do is the following

1. I have a Github repository "myrepo" forked from another, "theirrepo", that's 6 months behind, but has a few changes "myfeature" in it.
2. I want to move myfeature to a branch "B".
3. I then want to make myrepo's master branch identical to theirrepo's, including history.

That is, I want to get my repository back in line with the central repo, and still have my changes stored somewhere where I can look at them again in the future.

Seems simple enough, right?

I get this far:

```
git clone git://github.com/myrepo
git branch myfeature
git push myfeature origin
git remote add theirrepo git://github.com/theirrepo
git fetch theirrepo
```

At this point, I have these branches:

- master
- theirrepo/master
- myfeature

How do I get the changes out of theirrepo/master and write them over my master without merging, or retaining any history? I have a vague notion that this is what rebase is meant to do. However, the git tutorials all assume that I want to add my local changes to the end of the history - which I don't.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The next step is:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard theirrepo/master
```

Comment: Thank you - that worked. To complete the story, I also needed "git add *" (to track new files created in theirrepo/master) then "git push". Part of my confusion was thinking of "theirrepo/master" and "master" as two permanently different things.